# Why is my python CGI script slow on some machines?

Tags: python, cgi, nohup, slony

I'm running a python script on localhost to start slon daemons (Slony-I) to replicate databases. The problem is that on my machine the response is obtained instantly, but on other servers it takes a long time (blocking my application). In my script I start 3 process using nohup and &. Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import os
# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

separador = '_to_'

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
masterdb = form.getvalue('MASTERDBNAME')
slavedb = form.getvalue('SLAVEDBNAME')
masterhost = form.getvalue('MASTERHOST')
slavehost = form.getvalue('SLAVEHOST')
masteruser = form.getvalue('MASTERUSER')
masterpass = form.getvalue('MASTERPASS')
slaveuser = form.getvalue('SLAVEUSER')
slavepass = form.getvalue('SLAVEPASS')
clustername = form.getvalue('CLUSTERNAME')

def updateScript(name, masterdb, slavedb, masterhost, slavehost, masteruser, masterpass, slaveuser, slavepass, cluster):
    script = open(name, 'r')
    scriptData = script.read()
    script.close()

    newData = scriptData.replace('[masterdbname]', masterdb)
    newData = newData.replace('[slavedbname]', slavedb)
    newData = newData.replace('[masterhost]', masterhost)
    newData = newData.replace('[slavehost]', slavehost)
    newData = newData.replace('[masteruser]', masteruser)
    newData = newData.replace('[masterpass]', masterpass)
    newData = newData.replace('[slaveuser]', slaveuser)
    newData = newData.replace('[slavepass]', slavepass)
    newData = newData.replace('[clustername]', cluster)

    split = name.split('.')
    newname = split[0]+'_temp.'+split[1]

    script = open(newname, 'w')
    script.write(newData)
    script.close()

def runCall(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

def storeRunningDaemons():
    listdaemons = 'ps -aux |grep -E \'/usr/bin/slon.*'+separador+'\'|grep -v grep | awk \'{print \"/usr/bin/nohup \"$11\" \"$12\" \"$13\" \"$14\" \"$15\" \"$16\" &\"}\' > running_daemons.log'
    runCall(listdaemons)

    daemons = open('running_daemons.log', 'r')
    lines = daemons.readlines()
    daemons.close()

    slon_restore = open('dsg_slon.sh', 'wb')
    conteudo = ['#!/bin/bash\n'] + lines
    slon_restore.writelines(conteudo)
    slon_restore.close()

    runCall('chmod +x dsg_slon.sh')

# Updating scripts
updateScript('slony_subscribe.sh', masterdb, slavedb, masterhost, slavehost, masteruser, masterpass, slaveuser, slavepass, clustername)    

# Defining commands
slonsubscribe = '/usr/bin/nohup sh slony_subscribe_temp.sh >> subscribe.log &'
slonmastercmd = '/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/slon %s \"dbname=%s user=%s host=%s password=%s\" >> master.log &' % (clustername, masterdb, masteruser, masterhost, masterpass)
slonslavecmd = '/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/slon %s \"dbname=%s user=%s host=%s password=%s\" >> slave.log &' % (clustername, slavedb, slaveuser, slavehost, slavepass)

# Starting daemons
runCall(slonsubscribe)
runCall(slonmastercmd)
runCall(slonslavecmd)

# Updating running slon daemons
storeRunningDaemons()

# HTML return
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Starting replication</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Clustername = %s | Master DB = %s | Slave DB = %s</h2>" % (clustername, masterdb, slavedb)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

What can be happening?

Comment: There's a lot of work in the queue.
Use thread or pool.If you have static data, ready from the start the service.

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code?

Comment: I'll try to profile it.. But I'm really confused... The nohup with subprocess.call shouldn't block the script, right?

Comment: I solved my problem with a fresh linux install. The code was ok, there was something bad happening with my kubuntu for some strange reason.